# same pandas dataframes are not equal after storing it to database

Tags: python, pandas, postgresql

I have a pandas dataframe:
(edit: actual df)

```
date
2019-11-01 07:30:00+00:00    1148.144708
2019-11-01 07:45:00+00:00    1148.015876
2019-11-01 08:00:00+00:00    1147.911068
2019-11-01 08:15:00+00:00    1147.925240
2019-11-01 08:30:00+00:00    1148.007117
2019-11-01 08:45:00+00:00    1148.122853
2019-11-01 09:00:00+00:00    1148.251176
2019-11-01 09:15:00+00:00    1148.362736
2019-11-01 09:30:00+00:00    1148.423236
2019-11-01 09:45:00+00:00    1148.528360
Name: value, dtype: float64
```

I saved it into Postgres database using:

```
df.to_sql('test_pp', con=engine)
```

After when I retrieve it back from the DB as a new_df:
(edit: actual df)

```
date
2019-11-01 07:30:00+00:00    1148.144708
2019-11-01 07:45:00+00:00    1148.015876
2019-11-01 08:00:00+00:00    1147.911068
2019-11-01 08:15:00+00:00    1147.925240
2019-11-01 08:30:00+00:00    1148.007117
2019-11-01 08:45:00+00:00    1148.122853
2019-11-01 09:00:00+00:00    1148.251176
2019-11-01 09:15:00+00:00    1148.362736
2019-11-01 09:30:00+00:00    1148.423236
2019-11-01 09:45:00+00:00    1148.528360
Name: value, dtype: float64
```

both these dataframes are not equal. Why is that?

```
df.equals(new_df)
```

returns **False**.
Any idea?
P.S.: I also checked the order and shape and sorted it based on the date.

I also checked the indexes

```
DatetimeIndex(['2019-11-01 09:45:00+00:00'], dtype='datetime64[ns, UTC]', name='date', freq=None),
DatetimeIndex(['2019-11-01 09:45:00+00:00'], dtype='datetime64[ns, UTC]', name='date', freq=None))
```

and the dtypes

```
df['value'].dtypes, new_df['value'].dtypes
```

returns

```
(dtype('float64'), dtype('float64'))
```

strangely,

```
df['value'].iloc[-1:].index == new_df['value'].iloc[-1:].index
```

returns **True**

and

```
df['value'].iloc[-1].values == new_df['value'].iloc[-1].values
```

returns **False**

Comment: check the all values. Are `date` values just string?

Comment: With the code you've provided the dataframes are obviously going to be equal. Please provide the **actual** dataframe (or at least part of it) returned from the database. My guess would be that postgres does something to the dates, but without having seen the dataframe we're left to guess

Comment: seems you've a typo here `df.equals(df_new)` it should be `df.equals(new_df)`

Comment: thanks! I've edited. Yes @Lukas Thaler, postgres converts the datetime timezone. But that could not  be the problem here, as you can see they are on the same timezone.

Comment: @giosans, no. they are datetimeindex

Comment: The dataframes look unchanged on the surface, so it likely is a change in `dtype`. Can you run `df.dtypes` and `new_df.dtypes` and compare the output?

Comment: @LukasThaler yes they are the same. added to the new edit

Comment: The last value is the `2019-11-01 09:45:00+00:00    1148.528360` line? If so, are there any decimals that are not printed or is this the full length? And what precision dies the database operate in? Some loss in late decimals due to a change in precision is the last theory I can come up with right now

Comment: @LukasThaler Thanks! got it. That's not the full length. Actually, postgres rounded off the last 3 digits - (1148.5283597952682 to 1148.52835979527). The datatype in the table is  "double precision". How to solve this?

Comment: You'll have to ask a Postgres expert for that one I'm afraid. I'm not a huge database guy. But according to the documentation page you linked, specifying the column as a `numeric` one should resolve this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because of the [double precision](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/datatype-numeric.html) in Postgres. It rounded off the last 3 digits.